# Best way to get data continuously on NodeJS (or subscribe)

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, socket.io

I'm trying to write a socket application on NodeJS. This application should publish the data from the service in real time to the html. I can publish static data from socket to frontend. But the real data comes from my web service and contains different values for A1, A2 etc. I was thinking about sending XHR request to web service at certain intervals. But is there a better way to get current data in NodeJS instead of this solution?

Thanks in advance.

nodejs part

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);


app.get('/A1', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

app.get('/A2', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.emit('A1', { message: 'data for A1' });
    socket.emit('A2', { message: 'data for A2' });
});

server.listen(8080);
```

frontend:

```
var pathname = window.location.pathname;
pathname = pathname.substring(1);

var socket = io.connect('/');
socket.on(pathname, function(data) {
    console.log('Got announcement:', data.message);
});
```

Comment: Not really sure what you mean by "But the real data comes from my web service", as you've you've written it your web socket server is in the same place as your web service...?

Comment: Are there any errors or warnings showing up in the console?

Comment: @Dominic web service written in java and they are not in same place.

Comment: @FranciscoHanna my example code works fine. But I need to know best way to get data real time  instead of sending XHR request in every 5 seconds

Comment: You may want to checkout some service like AWS SNS or [this socket.io Java implementation](https://github.com/mrniko/netty-socketio). Or, as @Dominic says, your Java server could hit an endpoint on your socket server when needed.

Comment: I see. Your java server can send messages to your websocket server which can then be broadcast to clients. You can use the concept of channels for that e.g. 'java-service' vs 'clients'. You can require connections to the java-service channel to have a secret key. You should also use wss (secure) not ws.

Comment: Thank you both for sharing your ideas and very helpful solutions.